# Camera animated using Follow Path contraint wanders then Jumps back to path near end of animation

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I am animating a camera using the follow path constraint, with the fixed position checked and animating via the offset.

Near the end of my animation at the exact same spot (If I do not animated past 0.991 then jump will not occur) the camera Jumps as seen by these images showing the frame before and frame after jump. [image: Frame before jump] [image: Frame After Jump]

As seen by my dope sheet and my offset curve nothing occurs here that could warrant such a movement.

[image]
[image]

Has anyone had any dealings with said problem? Thank you in advance.

If I have not provided enough info please inform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. At first I thought that it was to do with the rotation applied to the camera. So I rigged the camera and used a null(empty) to rotate it. This did not fix it.

It was actually rather simple.

I had to increase the resolution of the active spline, 192 worked well for me.

[image]

I hope this helps anyone who ever has the same problem I did.

If you know of a different/better way of fixing said issue, by all means let me know.